# Why does `gulp-sass` not see my `mixins.scss` file?

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I'm using a `gulp-sass` plugin and it gives errors like

```
"Error: no mixin named font-base"
"Error: Undefined variable: "$background-color"
```

Apart from that I get a long list of errors which annoys me… and it does not let me find an error which breaks compilation if it happens. Renamed mixins.scss to _mixins.scss but it does not help.

## My `mixins.scss`

```
@mixin font-base ($size, $height) {
    font-size: $size;
    line-height: $height;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: $lavender;
    font-family: $base-font-family;
}
```

## My style.scss

```
@import "global/fonts";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "global/scafolding";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - find a mistake in gulp's task, it was:

```
    gulp.task("style", function() {
        gulp.src("source/sass/**/*.scss")
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("source/css"))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });
```

then I changed gulp.src from "source/sass/**/*.scss" to "source/sass/style.scss" and now everything is fine))